# Не выполняется условие после reverse

Tags: c++

Нужно проверить перевернута ли строка и сравнить ее со второй строкой, но программа работает неправильно и выводит NO когда должна выводить YES

```
if (n <= 15)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> s1[i];
            cin >> s2[i];
        }
        string word1 = string(s1);
        string word2 = string(s2);

        string wordReverse1(word1);
        reverse(begin(word1), end(word1));

        string wordReverse2(word2);
        reverse(begin(word2), end(word2));

        if (wordReverse1 == word2 || wordReverse2 == word1) cout << "YES" << endl;
            else cout << "No";
        
    
    }
        else cout << "Error";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте, что вы ввели. Нуль-символ есть или нет? По приведенному коду не видно, чтоб он у вас был, вот и получаете... Кстати, не вижу никакого смысла сравнивать обращения 2 раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что вы ввели. Как вы думаете, нуль-символ у вас есть или нет? :)

По приведенному коду не видно, чтоб он у вас был, вот и получаете неприятности.

Да и вводите вы как-то странно, чередуя символы строк:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> s1[i];
    cin >> s2[i];
}
```

Типа, при вводе `abcdef` в первую строку пойдет `ace` и `bdf` во вторую? Вы так и планировали?

Вобщем, проверяйте, что вы *реально* ввели. Не умеете с отладчиком проверить значение переменной — просто добавьте вывод `word1` и `word2`.

И, кстати, не вижу никакого смысла сравнивать обращения 2 раза. Зачем?

Comment: А как правильно ввести символы? Добавить цикл 
`for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) cout << s[j]` ?

Comment: А почему не просто `cin >> word1`? Или у вас могут быть пробелы? тогда `getline`...

Comment: Условие задачи такое, преобразовать массив символов в строку

Comment: С помощью второго цикла получилось корректно ввести массив, а как его занулить что бы он выводился корректно?
https://dpaste.org/s54N#L41,42,43,44,45,46,47

Comment: После ввода последнего символа добавить еще один - `0` (не `'0'`! именно `0`).